# Help! Whats up with my network?

Tags: router, routing, networking, nmap

I've just done a simple nmap scan of my network with nmap:
nmap -sP 192.168.1.1-255

```
networkserver@networkServer:~$ sudo nmap -sP 192.168.1.1-255

Starting Nmap 5.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2010-08-26 17:46 NZST
Host RTA1320.home (192.168.1.1) is up (0.00060s latency).
MAC Address: 00:26:B6:C9:E7:48 (Unknown)
Host 192.168.1.2 is up (0.00057s latency).
MAC Address: 00:23:69:16:85:D7 (Cisco-Linksys)
Host 192.168.1.3 is up (0.00015s latency).
MAC Address: 02:27:19:B4:61:DB (Unknown)
Host networkServer (192.168.1.50) is up.
Host 192.168.1.104 is up (0.0012s latency).
MAC Address: 00:1A:4D:9C:70:0E (Giga-byte Technology Co.)
Host 192.168.1.109 is up (0.0076s latency).
MAC Address: 78:E4:00:8E:FE:63 (Unknown)
Nmap done: 255 IP addresses (6 hosts up) scanned in 28.74 seconds
```

That seemed to take a rather long time, so I check with a friend on his network and it only took 2.74 secconds!

My network layout is:

```
                             /---WifiRouter----#laptop>
Modem----server---switch---->
                             \---#devbox
```

I figure something is wrong with the routing settings on my network but I'm not sure how to check it? Any ideas?

Comment: Which machine are you scanning from? What OS/Version etc?

Comment: I am scanning from "server", OS=Ubuntu 10.4

Comment: Ok I tried this:

nmap -sP 192.168.1.1 (modem)
...
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.72 seconds



nmap -sP 192.168.1.104 (LAPTOP)
...
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 13.68 seconds 


So the problem is the wifi router, I just tried plugging in a device into the router and the same problem happens. So it's not just over wifi connections but also wired ones! ARGH!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The network you checked was the same ? Machines / Os / topology. Also, do you (or he) have/has QOS enabled  on your / his switch ?

Also it would be helpful it you give the Ip's of every machine. (to know what is what).
Just to mention that it seems that your bottleneck is located on  192.168.1.104 (Giga-byte Technology Co.). What is it ?

Comment: 192.168.1.104 was it!

Answer (score 0):

Could you give the output of command (on the server): `# route -n` ?

Comment: Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0